# What's the keyboard shortcut to insert a comment on OSX Word 2008?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

No shortcut is listed in the menu, under Insert > Comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. (Apparently internally the operation is "Insert Annotation", not comment.) You can change this under `Tools` → `Customize Keyboard`...

Comment: Thank you! This is still the solution to insert a comment with a shortcut in Microsoft Word on macOS in 2023.